# 3d Hill generating algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, minecraft

Supposing you have a 3d box of cubes, with each cube having 3 indices: `(x,y,z)`, and 1 additional attribute to specify if it represents land or air.

Let's say that we have a 3d array to represent this box of cubes, with each cube being an element in the 3d array.

The following array, for example, would represent a bowl shaped piece of land:

```
y=0:        
0 0 0 0 0     
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1

y=1:
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1

y=2:
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1

y=3:
0 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

What is an algorithm such that given a selection box it would generate hills with `f` frequency and with average height of `h`, with `v` average variation in height?

We can assume that the lowest level of the bonding box is the "baseline", or "sea-level".

```
function makeTrees(double frequency, int height, double variation)
{
    //return 3d array.
}
```

I'm writing a minecraft [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-173/) filter plugin :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to decompose the problem into three parts:

1. Write a routine to generate the cubes for a single hill of height h. Start off by making this a simple cone (play with apex angles till you find something that looks pleasing)
2. Generate a set of n heights between h-v and h+v, using the random number generator of your choice
3. Place n mountains randomly on your cube. It doesn't matter if they intersect - indeed, it will lead to a better-looking range.

However, I'd also suggest abandoning this approach, and simply generate a [fractal terrain](http://gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html) within your bounding cube, then discretize it. You can play with the paramaters to your fractal generator to bound the height and variance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would like sinusoidal hills of frequency `f` (or rather, [wavenumber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) `f`, since "frequency" is usually used for temporal quantities) as a function of radius `r = sqrt(x^2+y^2)` from the center:

Define a threshold function like this:

[image]

Any element `(x,y,z)` with `z < z_m` will be land, and the rest will be air.

Comment: You don't say so in your question, but now I get the feeling that you want random-looking hills...

Comment: Yeah random looking hills is preferred. I want to give my land some random elevation to make it look more natural